# how to make all line of subsection in order and with space

Tags: line-spacing

```
\subsection{CLOSED :}
If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon , then the algebraic system is               called ' CLOSED ' .

Example :

1. Set of an integer is closed under + , - , $\times$ operator.

2. Set of an integer is not closed under / operator.

Let A = \{ $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\psi$ \}
```

I want these spaces which I'm not getting and in same order.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: the gap before Example and 1 and 2..

Comment: and gap before Let also

Comment: You want an extra space there in PDF?

Comment: actually when i an writing the above code..then in PDf i m not getting any space before Example and before 1 and 2

Comment: You should realize that, to LaTeX, many spaces are the same as one. Thus, the large number of spaces you have between `system is` and `called ' CLOSED '` has no more effect than one space. Similarly, blank lines serve only to separate paragraphs. To get extra space between lines you can either create it explicitly with `\vspace{...}`, or use an environment like `enumerate` that inserts extra space automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're making several mistakes in your code.

1. Math symbols should be confined inside a formula; an inline formula is surrounded either by `\(...\)` or `$...$`. So each item in the first example's list of operators should be between `$` signs. Conversely, the whole final formula must be surrounded by `$...$`: also `A` is a math symbol.
2. Never leave spaces before commas or other punctuation, unless you're writing in French where a space should precede semicolons, colons, question marks and interrogation marks.
3. Don't use capitals for emphasis; the most used method is italics, but LaTeX has an abstract command `\emph` for it. The defined word should not be set between quotes.
4. For enumerated lists, LaTeX provides the `enumerate` environment. I wouldn't leave vertical space before the ‘Examples:’ line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Algebraic systems}

\subsection{Closedness}

If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon, then the
algebraic system is called \emph{closed}.

Examples:
\begin{enumerate}
\item The set of integers is closed under the $+$, $-$, $\times$ operators.

\item The set of integers is not closed under the $/$ operator.
\end{enumerate}

Let $A = \{\alpha,\beta,\psi\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, we choose somewhat different approaches. Clearly you are the mathematician. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want something like that one way would be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\subsection{CLOSED :}
If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon , then the
algebraic system is called ' CLOSED ' .

\vspace{1\baselineskip} \noindent
Example :

\vspace{1\baselineskip} \noindent
1. Set of an integer is closed under + , - , $\times$ operator.

\vspace{1\baselineskip} \noindent
2. Set of an integer is not closed under / operator.

\vspace{1\baselineskip} \noindent
Let A = \{ $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\psi$ \}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would probably write it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection{CLOSED :}
If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon, then the
algebraic system is called `CLOSED'.

\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
Example:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Set of an integer is closed under +, -, $\times$ operator.
    \item Set of an integer is not closed under / operator.
\end{enumerate}
Let A = \{$\alpha$, $\beta$, $\psi$\}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe define something more fancy for the Example.